# Why is document.getElementById null in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodes

This is a website where the text is changing every second.

```
function changer() {
    if (typeof index == 'undefined') {
        index = 1;
    }

    if (index == 1) {
        change = document.getElementById("text");
        //alert(change);
        words = document.createTextNode("This text is always changing.");
        change.appendChild(words);
        change.parentNode.replaceChild(words, change);
        index = index + 1;
    } else {
        change = document.getElementById("text");
        //alert(change);
        words = document.createTextNode("Yes it is. Yes it is.");
        change.appendChild(words);
        change.parentNode.replaceChild(words, change);
        index = index - 1;
    }

    setTimeout('changer()', 1000);
}
```

The first time though the loop (when index == 1) document.getElementById("text") = [object HTMLDivElement], but the second time around it is null.

Why would something work once, and then not work a second time? But maybe someone can explain why and/or explain how to fix it.

This is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="changer.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="changer();">
<div contenteditable="true" id="text"><div/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You replaced it. It is now gone from the document.

Comment: We can't tell you how to fix it unless you tell us what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Just curious, where did you learned that `setTimeout` takes a string? I've seen that a lot lately and it's just bad practice! :)

Comment: Its container removed by this line:

    change.parentNode.replaceChild(words, change);

Answer (score 0):

There's a property in objects that you can set, `innerText`, that will replace the content of said object, so you can use it like this:

```
var index = 1;
function changer() {
    if (index == 1) {
        text.innerText = "This text is always changing.";
        index = index + 1;
    } else {
        text.innerText = "Yes it is. Yes it is.";
        index = index - 1;
    }
    setTimeout(changer, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its container removed by this line:

`change.parentNode.replaceChild(words, change);`

thats because there is no child ;)

```
document.createTextNode("Yes it is. Yes it is.");
```

doesnt make a child, its just plain text.

so the div will be replaced by the text. thats why its giving you a NULL

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. Here is my fixed code:

```
function changer() {

if (typeof index == 'undefined') {
index = 1;
}
if (typeof p == 'undefined') {
p = document.createElement("p");
}

if (index == 1) {

    words1 = document.createTextNode("This text is always changing.");
        if(typeof words2 !=='undefined'){
        p.replaceChild(words1, words2);
        }else{
        p.appendChild(words1);
        }
    index = index + 1;
}else{

    words2 = document.createTextNode("Yes it is. Yes it is.");
        if(typeof words1 !=='undefined'){
        p.replaceChild(words2, words1);
            }else{
            p.appendChild(words2);
            }
        index = index - 1;
}

    text = document.getElementById("text");
    text.appendChild(p);

setTimeout(changer, 1000);

}
```